# How to uninstall/reinstall Raderon 7500 driver?

Tags: drivers, xorg, ati, uninstall, radeon

How I can uninstall or reinstall my Radeon 7500 driver? Also, can I try a different Xorg version? My T40 (Thinkpad) is not getting 3D acceleration on Ubuntu 11.10. What is the best Ubuntu version if I want to enable effects in Compiz (like wobbling windows)?

I am not an advanced Linux user, but I have used Fedora, so I have a bit of experience. I no longer use Windows, unless I am using FruityLoops.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple drivers for ATI/AMD Radeon graphics cards, a proprietary one and a free, open-source one.

The free open-source driver is contained in the `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` package.

The proprietary driver is provided by the `fglrx` package.

Answer (score 0):

Compiz used to support the 7500 up to 0.8.6 (which was the version in ubuntu Maverick iir). The 0.9 branch (rewrite) of Compiz blacklisted the 7500 in 0.9.2 (the ubuntu Natty version) and completely fails to support it in 0.9.6 (the version in Oneiric).

So you're stuck. Either go back to Lucid / Maverick, or abandon Compiz and use KWin or something similar. There is a third-party package to install Compiz 0.8.6 in Natty , but no such package exists for Oneiric.

I suspect the 3D in your card is working fine. If you want to check then install mesa-utils (sudo apt-get install mesa-utils) and run glxgears to see a simple demo.